# Скрипт переноса данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: google-apps-script

Всем привет, хотел написать скрипт для переноса всех листов одной таблицы в другую с помощью скрипта, все получилось кроме одного НО, мне нужны исходные названия листов или назвать листы по новому строчкой кода, но я не могу написать ее коректно, из таблице надо перенести 20 листов, помогите пожалуйста. Вот сам код.

```js
function importSheets() {
  var url = "ссылка_на_документ";
  var origin = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = origin.getSheets();
  for (var sheet in sheets){
    sheets[sheet].copyTo(result)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто проверьте, если такого листа нет в приемнике, то добавьте имя к вставляемому листу, если есть, то пропустите или сделайте что-то иное.

```
  for (var sheet in sheets) {
    const ns = sheets[sheet].copyTo(result);
    const name = sheets[sheet].getName();
    if (!result.getSheetByName(name))
      ns.setName(name);
    else
      console.warn('Не могу переименовать, такой лист уже есть.')
  };
```

Другой вариант, когда нужно скопировать только то, чего нет

```
  for (var sheet in sheets) {
    const name = sheets[sheet].getName();
    if (!result.getSheetByName(name)) {
      const ns = sheets[sheet].copyTo(result);
      ns.setName(name);
    } else
      console.warn('Не могу скопировать, такой лист уже есть.')
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu(`▶️ МЕНЮ`)
    .addItem("✅ Копировать листы", "importSheets")
    .addToUi();
}

function importSheets() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const copySheetId = ui
    .prompt("Введите ID книги из которой копируем", ui.ButtonSet.OK)
    .getResponseText();
  if (copySheetId) {
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copySheetId).getSheets();
    const result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    for (let sheet in sheets) {
      let name = sheets[sheet].getName();
      if (!result.getSheetByName(name))
        sheets[sheet].copyTo(result).setName(name);
      else console.warn("Не могу переименовать, такой лист уже есть.");
    }
  } else ui.alert(`ID не введён!!!`);
}
```