# Скрипт переноса 1 листа из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: google-apps-script

Всем привет, нужен скрипт для переноса 1 определенного листа одной таблицы в другую, лучше через отправку из источника.
Нашел здесь [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488101/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E) что-то похожее, но не смог разобраться, как импортировать только 1 лист.

```js
function importSheets() {
  var url = "ссылка_на_документ";
  var origin = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = origin.getSheets();
  for (var sheet in sheets){
    sheets[sheet].copyTo(result)
  };
}
```

Перенос данных из 1 таблицы в другую не подходит, потому что картинки не переносятся, ну или есть какой-то способ перенести картинки.

Нужно отправить только 1 лист в другую таблицу, в нём текст и картинки в ячейках.

UPD. Получившийся результат, возможно "топорный", но рабочий.

```js
//Делаем кнопку для запуска скрипта
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu(`▶️ Меню`)
    .addItem("✅ Название кнопки", "userAction")
        .addToUi();
}
//Функция, удаляющая все листы, кроме одного
var del = function DeleteAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
  case "Имя листа, который не нужно удалять":
  break;
  default:
  ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);}}}
//Функция, которая копирует нужный лист с нужной таблицы
var rozn = function importSheets() {
    var origin = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID таблицы, откуда копируем').getSheetByName('Название листа, который копируем');
    var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    origin.copyTo(result).setName(origin.getName())
  }
//Функция, которая объединяет предыдущие две функции, чтобы запустить их по кнопке
function userAction(){
  del();
  rozn();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно сделать полную копию одного листа, то этой функции вам должно хватить:

```
function importSheets() {
  var origin = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID таблицы, с которой нужно скопировать лист').getSheetByName('Имя копируемого листа');
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  origin.copyTo(result).setName(origin.getName())
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Воспользовался вашим кодом. Доработал, чтобы удалять другие листы и заливать по новой нужный лист.

Comment: можете отметить мой ответ как решение